# Unable to start a fragment from a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Hello everyone i have a view pager named "viewpager" and two fragments named "Add_Create" and "Add_Create_2".I am using Tab layout to show different tabs.Now in one of the tabs there is "Add_Create" fragment.In Add_Create fragment there is a button and on that button click i want to show Add_Create_2 fragment.Below is my code that i have tried

```
 Add_Create_2 add= new Add_Create_2();
            FragmentTransaction transaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.viewpager,add);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
```

Now this code is present in first fragment named "Add_Create".
[image: Now both the fragments are mixed up]

Comment: This link might be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/38233253/6178443

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be at the viewPager. What kind of element is this? If it  is a ViewPager, you cannot load it a Fragment. You should to create on it maybe a RelativeLayout, and it will be your fragment container.

Comment: <Linear Layout>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</Linear Layout>

Comment: Try this:

<Linear Layout>
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager android:id="@+id/viewpager" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@android:color/white" app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
 
 <RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"/>
 
 </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</Linear Layout>

And at the transaction:
transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,add);

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `getFragmentManager()`, use `getSupportFragmentManager()`. Since you're calling it from a fragment, maybe `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: I looked at your comment in Davo's answer and realized that you are trying to replace a Fragment with an id 'viewpager' which is in the Main activity's Layout and not in the 'Add_Create' Fragments layout. This is the reason it is failing

Comment: so what should i do? i mean do i have to move view pager to Add_Create? or there is any work around available ? @Leonard

Comment: Best option is to create a RelativeLayout with width and height = 'match_parent' and  id say 'frag' inside 'Add_Create' Layout file. Every other thing should go inside this RelativeLayout. Then in java, in OnCreateView() since it is a Fragment,  getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().begintransaction().add(R.id.frag, new Add_Create_2()).commit();

Comment: @Leonard i have edited my question and posted a screen shot please look it now

Comment: Inside the Layout of 'Add_Create', the buttons, text views and all should be inside a RelativeLayout, like I mentioned in my last comment. Then give it layout_width="match_parent" and layout_height="match_parent" then android:id="@+id/frag" . then in the java code of 'Add_Create', in OnCreateView() since it is a Fragment, add  getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().begintransaction().add(R.id.frag, new Add_Create_2()).commit();

Comment: Everything is under relative layout sir

Comment: OK. Just use the id of the Layout in your java code instead of R.id.viewpager

Comment: i am using that layout id instead of view pager

Comment: And using getSupportFragmentManager? Any change?

Comment: No nothing i am affraid

Comment: Sorry but I can't seem to figure out what's causing that